# Amount change in opportunity

Tags: apex, trigger, opportunity, record-type

I'm trying to create trigger where if record type is Revenue Risk then amount should be saved in negative value,
Here's my code in which I'm having error. I tried it two ways, second is in comments.. none of them is working

```
public with sharing class amountValidator {

//pull data of Opportunity in list
public static void validateAmount (list<Opportunity> oppList){


    oppList = [Select amount FROM Opportunity WHERE RecordType.Name IN ('Revenue Risk')];

    for(Opportunity opportunities : oppList){

        if(oppList.amount >= '0'){

            oppList.amount = oppList.amount * '-1';

        }
    }


        /*Map<String,Schema.RecordTypeInfo> rtMapByName = d.getRecordTypeInfosByName();
        Schema.RecordTypeInfo rtByName =  rtMapByName.get('Revenue Risk');

        for(Opportunity each : oppList){

            if(rtByName.size == 0){
            }

            else{

                if(oppList.Amount >= 0){

                    oppList.Amount = oppList.Amount*-1;

                }

            }

        }*/
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  Is it possible your select is not returning records?

Comment: It is compile time error not run time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code for Trigger:

```
trigger Risk_NegativeQuantity on OpportunityLineItem (before insert) {
    set<id> oppid = new set<id>();
    for (OpportunityLineItem  oli : trigger.new)
    { 
        oppid.add(oli.opportunityid);
    }
    Id RevenueRisk= Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Revenue Risk').getRecordTypeId();
    list<opportunity> opplist = [select id, recordtype.name,recordtypeid from opportunity where id in : oppid ];
    for (OpportunityLineItem  oli : trigger.new)
    {    
        for (opportunity opp: opplist)
        {
            if (oli.opportunityid == opp.id)
            {
                if(opp.recordtype.name == 'Revenue Risk')
                {
                    if(oli.Quantity > 0)
                    {
                       oli.Quantity = oli.Quantity * -1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is your exact code, don't forget to declare oppList. You need to update each opportunity in the list if its amount is over 0. No need to check equal to 0, since you can't have a negative 0.

```
List<Opportunity> oppList = [Select amount FROM Opportunity WHERE RecordType.Name IN ('Revenue Risk')];

    for(Opportunity opp : oppList){

        if(opp.amount > 0){

            opp.amount = - opp.amount;

        }
    }
```

Also, assuming this is not coming from a trigger, you might also need to actually update the data in the database. Just add this line on the end of the code : :

```
update oppList;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is only going to work if you do not use opportunity line items or quotes. Otherwise the amount gets locked/synced to those values and you need to run your trigger context on them instead.

trigger

```
trigger amountValidatorForRisks on Opportunity (before insert, before update) {
    amountValidator.validateAmount(trigger.new);
}
```

class

```
public with sharing class amountValidator {

        public static void validateAmount (list<Opportunity> oppList){

            Map<String,Schema.RecordTypeInfo> recordTypes = Opportunity.sObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByName();
            Id revenueRiskType = recordType.get('Revenue Risk').getRecordTypeId();

            for(Opportunity opportunities : oppList){

                if(opportunities.RecordTypeId == revenueRiskType && opportunities.amount > 0){

                    opportunities.amount =  opportunities.amount * -1;

                }
       }
}
```